Is this counted as stealing?
For context: I was playing an arcade game called wangan midnight.
The whole jist of the situation is, there were some guests who swiped their cards a lot and their credits were stored inside the machine, so this person swiped 7 times and left after only using the machine once.
After they left the machine, I saw this opportunity and I used the machine to play for 6 remaining times(6 credits) for free, my mother said I was stealing, am I really stealing?
